# Convert array of objects to object of arrays using lodash

Tags: arrays, object, key, underscore.js, lodash

The title is a little bit confusing but I essentially want to convert this:

```
[
    {a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
    {a: 4, b: 5, c:6},
    {a: 7, b: 8, c:9}
]
```

into:

```
{
  a: [1,4,7],
  b: [2,5,8],
  c: [3,6,9]
}
```

using lodash (requirement). Any ideas???

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using lodash that [**maps**](https://lodash.com/docs#map) across the keys and plucks the values for each key from the data before finally using [**_.zipOobject**](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject) to build the result.

```
var keys = _.keys(data[0]);

var result = _.zipObject(keys, _.map(keys, key => _.map(data, key)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for `_.map` [here](https://lodash.com/docs#map)

```
input = [
    {a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
    {a: 4, b: 5, c:6},
    {a: 7, b: 8, c:9}
];

output = {};

_.map(input, function(subarray){
    _.map(subarray, function(value, key){
            output[key] || (output[key] = []);
            output[key].push(value);
    });
});

console.log(output);
```