# Convert array of objects to an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following structure

```
var nights = [
    { "2016-06-25": 32, "2016-06-26": 151, "2016-06-27": null },
    { "2016-06-24": null, "2016-06-25": null, "2016-06-26": null },
    { "2016-06-26": 11, "2016-06-27": 31, "2016-06-28": 31 },
];
```

And I want to transform it to:

```
{ 
    "2016-06-24": [null], 
    "2016-06-25": [32, null], 
    "2016-06-26": [151, null, 11], 
    "2016-06-27": [null, 31], 
    "2016-06-28": [31] 
}
```

What's the shortest way to solve this? I have no problems with using Underscore, Lodash or jQuery.

My current code is:

```
var out = {};
for (var i = 0; i < nights.length; i++) {
    for (var key in nights[i]) {
        if (out[key] === undefined) {
            out[key] = [];
        }
        out[key].push(nights[i][key]);
    }
}
```

It's similar to [Convert array of objects to object of arrays using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638450/convert-array-of-objects-to-object-of-arrays-using-lodash) but that has all keys present in each object.

Comment: What solution do you have?

Comment: Your object has error. You can't use `-` in `key` without `"` or `'`.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Looping over every object in turn, creating a new one. Too messy & dirty to post here, it's an embarrassment

Comment: @Tushar code added to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the following snippet (no need for lodash etc):

```js
const x = [{ '2016-06-25': 32, '2016-06-26': 151, '2016-06-27': null }, { '2016-06-24': null, '2016-06-25': null, '2016-06-26': null }, { '2016-06-26': 11, '2016-06-27': 31, '2016-06-28': 31 }, ];
let y = {};

x.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    y[key] = (y[key] || []).concat([obj[key]]);
  });
});

console.log(y)
```

Comment: When I run your snippet it gives me two errors as well as the answer (Chrome, latest)

Comment: Same error, appearing twice: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, I'm sorry. A short google search though shows that there are other users having the same issue with the snippets in stackoverflow. Try running it in the browser's console by copy pasting. You should not get any error then (as this seems to be an issue with stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one-liner. Uses map to map keys into array of objects with properties of the keys. Then maps the original array to only that property and sets it as the value of the property. One issue with this way is that it will only use the properties of the first object in the array. So if other objects have properties that aren't in the first object they will be ignored.

```
const output = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(input[0]).map(props => ({[props]: input.map(prop => prop[props])})))
```

Edit: the output was in the wrong format, fixed

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's important to add some explanation to your code instead of just supplying a code-only answer.

Comment: Did my best its a little hard to explain

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array and the over the keys of the object and build a new object with the keys as new keys.

```js
var data = [{ '2016-06-25': 32, '2016-06-26': 151, '2016-06-27': null }, { '2016-06-24': null, '2016-06-25': null, '2016-06-26': null }, { '2016-06-26': 11, '2016-06-27': 31, '2016-06-28': 31 }, ],
    result = {};

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        result[k] = result[k] || [];
        result[k].push(o[k]);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Typescript -- obviously you can remove the types while working in JavaScript.

Assumption: The array of objects coming into the function will always have the same kind and number of object keys

```
mapperArrayOfJsonsToJsonOfArrays(inputArrayOfJsons: any): any {
    if (inputArrayOfJsons.length > 0) {
        let resultMap = {};
        let keys: any[] = Object.keys(inputArrayOfJsons[0]);
        keys.forEach((key: any) => {
            resultMap[key] = [];
        });

        inputArrayOfJsons.forEach((element: any) => {
            let values: any[] = Object.values(element);
            let index = 0;
            values.forEach((value: any) => {
                resultMap[keys[index]].push(value);
                index = index + 1;
            });
        });
        return resultMap;
    }
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove types considering there were no generics used?