# Converting xlsx to JSON and storing in a specific format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, xlsx

I am working on a project and I am stuck at one point:

so I have xlsx sheet with some data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knNes.png)

and when I convert to JSON like this :

> ```
> if (selectedFile) {
> const formData = new FormData();
> formData.append("file", selectedFile);
> const workbook = XLSX.read(await selectedFile.arrayBuffer(), {
> type: "array",
>       });
> const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
> const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
> const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });
> }
> ```

and console.log(jsonData):

the result is it take each row separately and make object of each row:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZCHW.png)

but I want this jsonData to be stored in a different way

> ```
>  `if (selectedFile) {
> const formData = new FormData();
> formData.append("file", selectedFile);
> const workbook = XLSX.read(await selectedFile.arrayBuffer(), {
> type: "array",
>       });
> const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
> const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
> const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });
>
> if (jsonData.length > 0) {
> const headers = data[0];
>
> Create a dictionary to store column names and their values as arrays
> const columnDict: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};
>
> headers.forEach((header: string) => {
> columnDict[header] = data
>             .slice(1)
>             .map((row: any) => row[headers.indexOf(header)]);
>         });
>
> Update state with the column data
> setColumnData(columnDict);
>       }
> }`
> ```

````
I have tried like this but now :

I am expecting it like :

> ```
> Chemicals: ["Silicon","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Diameter: [1,"2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Effect endpoint: ["Feret Minimal","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Effect endpoint type: ["Median","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Endpoint: ["Nano","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Endpoint Method: ["Invest1","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Endpoint category: ["Solid","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Material: ["Light","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Medium: ["CORE","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Name: ["1.1_SiC@TiO2_60","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Percentage: ["0.22","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> Project: ["Sunshine","2nd value", "3rd value",....]
> ```

all the values would be in a array according to the corresponding headers.

Thank you so much in advance
````

Comment: you can look into converting array of objects to an object of arrays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988451/convert-array-of-objects-to-an-object-of-arrays