# Convert object of arrays to array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, lodash, underscore.js

I have source data in the following format (object of arrays):

```
{
    value: [
      59, 58, 62, 58, 56, 57, 57, 65, 81, 81
    ],
    dayOfWeek: [
      'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday',
      'Friday',   'Monday', 'Friday',   'Tuesday'
    ],
    dayOrNight: [
      'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'
    ]
}
```

And I want the data transformed into the following format (array of objects):

```
[
    {
        value: 59,
        dayOfWeek: 'Thursday',
        dayOrNight: 'N'
    },
    {
        value: 58,
        dayOfWeek: 'Friday',
        dayOrNight: 'D'
    },
    {
        value: 62,
        dayOfWeek: 'Saturday',
        dayOrNight: 'N'
    },
    ...
]
```

This is kinda the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36638450/4070848).

What is the appropriate combination of commands to do this, whether using e.g. lodash or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `map` method and accessing by key to object, we can achieve desired result:

```
data.value.map((s, i) => ({value: s, 
   dayOfWeek: data.dayOfWeek[i], dayOrNight: data.dayOrNight[i]}));
```

An example:

```js
let data = {
    value: [
      59, 58, 62, 58, 56, 57, 57, 65, 81, 81
    ],
    dayOfWeek: [
      'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday',
      'Friday',   'Monday', 'Friday',   'Tuesday'
    ],
    dayOrNight: [
      'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'
    ]
};

const result = data.value.map((s, i) => ({value: s, 
   dayOfWeek: data.dayOfWeek[i], dayOrNight: data.dayOrNight[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

UPDATE:

This is slightly modified your approach:

```js
let data = {
    value: [
      59, 58, 62, 58, 56, 57, 57, 65, 81, 81
    ],
    dayOfWeek: [
      'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday',
      'Friday',   'Monday', 'Friday',   'Tuesday'
    ],
    dayOrNight: [
      'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'D', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'
    ]
};

const result = Object.values(data)[0].map((s, i) => {
    let obj = {};
    for (let key in data) {
            obj[key] = data[key][i];
    }
    return obj;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: neat!  any way of doing this without having to include the property names?  Ideally it would be generic and future-proof to deal with any number of different properties, not just those that happen to be present in the data now.  Other than maybe naming the property that is used as the basis for the map function (i.e. `value` here)... the rest would ideally not be named specifically.

Comment: @drmrbrewer thanks! what names would you insert instead of dayOrNight, dayOfWeek, value if there would not be property names?

Comment: sorry, by "not including the property names" I mean not hard-coding them into the conversion function, but just reading them dynamically from the source data object instead.  That way, if a new array is added to the data object later (with a new property name) it would automatically be handled by the conversion function still... probably just loop through the keys in the object... I'll give it a try unless you get there first!

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/18y9Lbmn/ ... I guess it's not using lodash as per question but who cares.  Slightly odd that it has to reference data.value... kinda arbitrary because it doesn't actually refer to that within the map function.

Comment: @drmrbrewer I slightly modified your approach, please, see my updated reply.

Comment: ah yes, neatly side-stepping the arbitrary use of one of the object properties as a basis for the map function.